# Using variables as slice indices for python

Tags: python, string, slice

For a class I am learning how to slice integers. In the code below the variable `halflength` is equal to half of the length of the variable `message`.

```
new = message[halflength::]
```

`halflength` is equal to an integer, however whenever I run this code I get this error:

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an `__index__` method

Basically I need to try and create a new string that is equal to the second half of the original string.

Example: original string 1234 would produce 34 as the new string.

Comment: can you show us where you are defining `halflength`?

Comment: It works for me with an arbitrary integer. I feel like you have a float accidentally.

Comment: Show us how you initialized `halflength`. It does not seem to be an integer.

Comment: This is not enough information to go on. Please put your code here. Oftentimes there error is introduced much before it is found.

Comment: You may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is you get a float type for halfLength after division, try to cast it to int, or use integer division

```
halfLength = int(halfLength)
```

or

```
halfLength = len(message) // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

to do what you want to do try something like this:

```
halfLength=len(message)//2
newMessage=message[halfLength::]
```

if you get the length this way it will always be an integer that you can then use to get parts of stings with.

Comment: `len(message) // 2` *

Comment: sorry just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure halflength is of type Integer.
You can use "isinstance" method to verify.

```
# python
 Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2016, 04:20:16 
 >>> halflength = "4"
 >>> isinstance(halflength,int)`
 False`
 >>> halflength=4
 >>> isinstance(halflength,int)
 True
 >>>
```

Try This:

```
message[int(halflength)::]
```